# javascript - adding one div at a time when the add more is clicked

Tags: javascript

How can I append a div once only every time the add more is clicked?
right now it copies everything inside the div and doubles it under..

http://jsfiddle.net/gkf5T/

```
<script>
function addInput(divName){
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
</script>
<div id="add_more_cat">
    <select name="category">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    </select>                                           
</div>
<a href="#" onClick="addInput('add_more_cat');">+ Add more</a>
```

Comment: You could simplify the operation by looking at Jquery to cut the syntax down and to use jQueries clone operation on a base copy of your div, so you can add to the display div each time it is done.. But ... since you did not specify its in Jquery no answer posted.

Comment: What is the expected result after `addInput` is called once?

Comment: @alexmac could you show me in an answer the jquery code of doing this?

Comment: What did you expect, it's doing exactly what you told you it to do. If you need the HTML before you change it, store in a variable in a higher scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to clone the same tag every time and you add the new element to the same tag too. What you could probably do is create a template tag, clone the template and add the clone to a new tag instead. That way, each time you click on 'Add more' you'll end up adding only one more select.

Try this fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/gkf5T/1/

```
<script>
function addInput(divName, template){
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
      document.getElementById(template).appendChild(newdiv);
}
</script>
<div id="template">
    <select name="category">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    </select>                                           
</div>
<div id="add_more_cat">
</div>
<a href="#" onClick="addInput('template', 'add_more_cat');">+ Add more</a>
```

Comment: This worked! I am wondering about that shorter version in jquery that alexmac is talking about above

Answer (score 1):

You can use cloneNode

```
<script>
function addInput(divName){
    var refEl = document.getElementById(divName);// refEl can be anything ex: document.body
   var clone = refEl.cloneNode(true);
   refEl.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, refEl.nextSibling);
}
</script>
<div id="add_more_cat">
    <select name="category">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
    </select>                                           
</div>
<a href="#" onClick="addInput('add_more_cat');">+ Add more</a>
```

try it here : http://jsfiddle.net/zLKXf/

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have an empty div

```
<div id="display></div>
```

Assume (yes ass-u-me) you have a row you want to insert over and over

```
<div id="add_more_cat">some html text whatever even extra divs</div>
```

In jQuery you could

```
var cloned = $("#add_more_cat").clone();
cloned.attr('id', someUnique); // this makes sure each area is addressable 

$("#display").append(cloned);
$("#display".show();  // sometimes its best to hide first if doing a loop appends. So if so use the hide before the loop
```

A working example is on my github [media data](https://github.com/alexmac131/mediaData)

Comment: editing still , some errors, not sure where my other bits went so correcting

Comment: this will work yes but I guess I should've mentioned that later I will have to somehow record what was selected from the dropdown and if it's all cloned I don't know how that will work

Comment: Yes, its just an example , not an answer but you asked for a example in jQuery, you can change the properties of the cloned div without affecting the original and then reuse the original again and again. My example link is not related to your question but show the operation of it in a practical setting.